# How to project LiDAR points into camera according to literature

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, robotics, matlab-cvst, extrinsic-parameters

For my project I was trying 3D LiDAR to Camera projection. I was recommended MATLAB LiDAR-Camera modules for calibration and then use the results for the projection on a live stream of the data.

In MATLAB, I got the rotation matrix ( R ), the translation matrix ( T ) and the camera intrinsic matrix ( M ). When using the MATLAB tools I am getting the results as follows :
[MATLAB generated projection for the same values of R, T and M](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8npG.png)

But using the literature in which the projection matrix is given as

( M 0 )x( [[ R T ], [ 0 1]] ) to get from a [x y z 1] to [u v w], I am getting the following result :

[Projection of M, R and T as per the literature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvs5b.png)

M, R,T as calculated from MATLAB

```
M = array([[904.4679,   0.    , 596.9176],
       [  0.    , 814.7088, 349.8212],
       [  0.    ,   0.    ,   1.    ]])

R = array([[ 0.124 , -0.0038,  0.9923],
       [-0.9912,  0.0474,  0.124 ],
       [-0.0475, -0.9989,  0.0021]])

T = array([[-0.56  ,  0.241 , -0.4454]])
```

A code snippet looks like this

```
rotation = np.array([[0.1240,-0.0038,0.9923],                                                       [-0.9912,0.0474,0.1240],[-0.0475,-0.9989,0.0021]])
traslation = np.array([[-0.5600,0.2410,-0.4454]])
traslation_1 = np.array([[-0.4454,0.2410,-0.5600]])
intrinsic = np.array([[904.4679,0,596.9176],[0,814.7088,349.8212],[0,0,1]])

a = np.concatenate((rotation,np.array([[0,0,0]])), axis =0)
b = np.concatenate((traslation_1.T, np.array([[1]])), axis =0)
c = np.concatenate((a,b), axis =1)

print('\n Extrinsic:\n \n',c)
d = np.concatenate((intrinsic, np.array([[0,0,0]]).T), axis =1)
print('\n Intrinsic:\n \n',d)
e = np.matmul(d,c)
print("\n Final:\n \n", e)
df = pd.read_csv('out_file.csv')

img = cv2.imread('images/0001.png')
v1_max = 0
v2_max = 0
uv = []
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
 
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    point = np.array([[df['x'].iloc[i],df['y'].iloc[i],df['z'].iloc[i],1]]).T
    v = np.matmul(e, point)
    v = v/v[2]
    if v[0]<=720 and v[0] > 0  and v[1] < 1280 and v[1] > 0:
        img[int(np.floor(v[0])),int(np.floor(v[1]))] = [0,255,255] 
            
                      
        
cv2.imwrite('file.png', img)
```

Hardware configuration :

Velodyne 64 Channel LiDAR @ 10 HZ

Camera : 1280*720 monocular camera

Checkerboard : 10*7 with 10 cm of pattern and a padding .

I need some help as to how I cam take the parameters from the MATLAB and do the same in the scripts and get the near results .

I am expecting as to where I am going wrong when projecting the LiDAR points onto the camera, as to when I am using MATLAB functions I am getting a correct projection. Same is not there with the literature.

Comment: hint: the camera intrinsic matrix is a **projection matrix**... -- please present a [mre]. -- are you trying to write python code?

Comment: Thank you for your mention, this is my first question on the form. I have updated the code.

Comment: that's still not a MRE. it's not executable as is. code is incomplete and there's no input data. -- `v = v/v[2]`, that's what I was hoping to see. that operation should be good. the rest is not. what you do with `rotation` is complete nonsense. you need the entire `R` matrix. I won't continue debugging this. just review whatever course material or books you have, thoroughly, and figure out how you got to this point. make sure you understand the required transformations and what meaning each matrix has.